# Strip Word Html Tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need to strip Word HTML tags in specific places.  At the moment I'm doing this :

```
public string CleanWordStyle(string html)
{
    StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();
    sc.Add(@"<table\b[^>]*>(.*?)</table>");
    sc.Add(@"(<o:|</o:)[^>]+>");
    sc.Add(@"(<v:|</v:)[^>]+>");
    sc.Add(@"(<st1:|</st1:)[^>]+>");
    sc.Add(@"(mso-bidi-|mso-fareast|mso-spacerun:|mso-list: ign|mso-ascii|mso-hansi|mso-ansi|mso-element|mso-special|mso-highlight|mso-border|mso-yfti|mso-padding|mso-background|mso-tab|mso-width|mso-height|mso-pagination|mso-theme|mso-outline)[^;]+;");
    sc.Add(@"(font-size|font-family):[^;]+;");
    sc.Add(@"font:[^;]+;");
    sc.Add(@"line-height:[^;]+;");
    sc.Add(@"class=""mso[^""]+""");
    sc.Add(@"times new roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;");
    sc.Add(@"verdana&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;");
    sc.Add(@"<p> </p>");
    sc.Add(@"<p>&nbsp;</p>");
    foreach (string s in sc)
    {
        html = Regex.Replace(html, s, "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }
    html = Regex.Replace(html, @"&nbsp;", @"&#160;"); //can not be read by as XmlDocument if not!
    return html;
}
```

Right now I am stripping whole HTML for `<p>` tags with `sc.Add(@"<p> </p>");`, but what I want is : if I hit table tags, it should stop replacing until it hits a table end tag. Is it possible?

Comment: I give a solution but now that I think again, is remove and the word formating, just keep the text... I do not know if is what you look for, but the use of the HTMLAgilityPack is the idea.

Comment: My custummer want to have that everything inside table tags shouldnt be touched, but everything else around should be stripped. its wasnt exactly the solution i was looking for

Comment: Look at HTMLAgilityPack, this is the idea, this can give you the DOM and from there you can keep the part that you wish for.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression can work for a line or for very simple html struct.

If you won to do really do work with minimum code, get the HTMLAgilityPack from http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ and get all the text from the inner values of all tags.

It will be simple as:

```
public string CleanWordStyle(string htmlPage)
{
  HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
  doc.LoadHtml(htmlPage);

  return doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: Instead of going through all of the child nodes and adding to a stringbuilding you can just return the innerttext of the root node.

Comment: no problem. This won't ONLY strip word styles though. It will strip all html inside the root.